# Filtering a SET with two dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a fact table say `WhsFactJob` where we have `CreatedTimeKey` and `InProgressTimeKey` and I have a measure where Job Count.

I am trying to create a Calculated measure which will fetch me the job count whose `CreatedTimeKey` falls between `1(1:00 AM)` and `2(2:00 AM)` and `InProgressTimeKey` also falls with the same `1(1:00 AM)` and `2(2:00 AM)`.

I tried to use `SUM` and `Except`, But it errors out saying `Except` has to use the same hierarchy.( `CreatedTimeKey` and `InprogressTime` Key are two seperate dimensions.

Any suggestions would help.

Here is the MDX example I am trying out.

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Sum] AS 
   SUM(
      EXCEPT(
         {[Created Time].[Hour].&[0]:[Created Time].[Hour].&[14]},
         {[In Progress Time].[Hour].&[0]:[In Progress Time].[Hour].&[14]}
      )
     ,[Measures].[Job Count]
   ) 
SELECT 
    [Measures].[Sum] ON 0 
FROM [Cube]
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please give a [mcve]! Thank you!

Comment: WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Sum] AS Sum(EXCEPT({[Created Time].[Hour].&[0]:[Created Time].[Hour].&[14]},{[In Progress Time].[Hour].&[0]:[In Progress Time].[Hour].&[14]}),[Measures].[Job Count]) 
SELECT
    [Measures].[Sum] ON 0
FROM
    [Cube]

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting code in the comments!

Comment: sorry to comment again. For some reason, I cannot edit the post. I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @JStephen what's hour 14? Your question says hour 1 and 2.

Comment: Did you want jobs created between 1-2 AND in progress between 1-2? Or did you want OR? Just wondering why you thought EXCEPT would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear why you're using EXCEPT.  How about this:

```
SUM
(
CROSSJOIN(
  {[Created Time].[Hour].&[0]:[Created Time].[Hour].&[14]},
  {[In Progress Time].[Hour].&[0]:[In Progress Time].[Hour].&[14]}
          )
,[Measures].[Job Count]
)
```

Comment: This solution absolutely works. Thanks for the response !!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get rid of the exception by cross-joining each set to members from the other set: not sure if the result of the query will be useful though - currently I'm unable to test the following:

The dimensionality of the two sets of tuples within the `EXCEPT` function should now be the same:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sum] AS 
   SUM(
      EXCEPT(
         {[Created Time].[Hour].&[0]:[Created Time].[Hour].&[14]}
         *[In Progress Time].[Hour].[Hour].MEMBERS
        , [Created Time].[Hour].[Hour].MEMBERS
        *{[In Progress Time].[Hour].&[0]:[In Progress Time].[Hour].&[14]}
      )
     ,[Measures].[Job Count]
   ) 
SELECT 
    [Measures].[Sum] ON 0 
FROM [Cube];
```